# Editing site with javascript

Tags: javascript, edit

I'm trying to make browser extension using javascript. I would like to create a code, which will modify the appearance of the website. I already know how to change the text on the website, but I would like to know how to add additonal elements.

Users see on the website a table with two rows like in the picture. I would like to make a script which adds additional column. Is it possible to make? If so, how can I do it (I think I have to edit site source but I dunno how)?

Pic: 
[image: http://postimg.org/image/9rdwsb1o1]

Comment: This is a very broad question. Try to narrow it down or show us what you have tried. More info http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I only know the class name of this table and grades which are in <span>. There are no id's.

Comment: For the most part, browser extensions update the page using the same code that you would in regular JavaScript.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? If not what have you tried last week. Feel free to share you answer, by answering your own question and providing atleast a small explanation.